# Mail is not sent via php mail() on CentOS7 DirecAdmin Exim php fcgi

Tags: php, email, sendmail, exim, fcgi

I spent the whole day trying to fix this problem, so I decided to share. Maybe it will save someone time)

**Problem:** Mail is not sent via php mail();
The Exim log shows nothing.

**System:**

- CentOS7
- DirecAdmin with CustomBuild 2.0.0
- Exim 4
- php fcgi (5.6 ... 7.4)

It is noteworthy that through the console mail is sent normaly, like:

```
echo "Subject: test" | / usr / sbin / sendmail -v my@mail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

**The solution was simple:**

Disable jailshell

**It was easy:**

DirectAdmin - Account Manager - Users - Select User - Modify

*and / or*

Manage User Packages / Edit Package

**Uncheck in user settings: Jailed**